# Norm on semi vector spaces possible or trivial?

Tags: functional-analysis

Because i always see positives spaces over positive semi fields and nowhere it has anything negative?So is it a trival case or not necsessary to define norm ?Since norm makes everything positive

Comment: A bilinear form with negative eigenvalues does not define a norm.

Comment: Sorry ..Can we define norm in semi vector spaces?

Comment: If a bilinear form $b$ is positive semidefinite but not positive definite, then there's a nonzero vector $x$ such that $b(x, x) =0$, so its norm would be $0$.